# how can i make formatted json file in c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to make a formatted json file in C#.

I want to make like this:

```
{
    "LiftPositioner" : [
        "LiftMax" : 5,
        "LiftMin" : 0
    ], 

    "Temperature" : [
        "CH0_Temp" : 25,
        "CH1_Temp" : 25
    ]
}
```

but the result was

```
{
 "LiftMax": 5,
 "LiftMin": 0,
 "CH0_Temp": 25,
 "CH1_Temp": 25
}
```

This is my code :

```
var json = new JObject();
json.Add("LiftMax", Convert.ToInt32(radTextBox_LiftMax.Text));
json.Add("LiftMin", Convert.ToInt32(radTextBox_LiftMin.Text));

json.Add("CH0_Temp", Convert.ToInt32(radTextBox_CH0.Text));
json.Add("CH1_Temp", Convert.ToInt32(radTextBox_CH1.Text));

string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
File.WriteAllText(@"ValueSetting.json", strJson);
```

What do I have to change in code?

Comment: Should the values of `LiftPositioner` and `Temperature` be lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be running `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` anyways, you may have an easier go of it by just creating an anonymous type with your values. The following would get you your desired result:

```
var item = new
{
    LiftPositioner = new[] 
    { 
        new 
        {
            LiftMax = 5,
            LiftMin = 0
        }
    },
    Temperature = new[] 
    {
        new
        {
            CH0_Temp = 25,
            CH1_Temp = 25
        }
    }
};
string strJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(strJson);
```

Which outputs the following:

```
{
  "LiftPositioner": [
    {
      "LiftMax": 5,
      "LiftMin": 0
    }
  ],
  "Temperature": [
    {
      "CH0_Temp": 25,
      "CH1_Temp": 25
    }
  ]
}
```

If you don't want lists for the `LiftPositioner` and `Temperature` properties, you could reduce this down to:

```
var item = new
{
    LiftPositioner = 
    new 
    {
        LiftMax = 5,
        LiftMin = 0
    },
    Temperature = 
    new
    {
        CH0_Temp = 25,
        CH1_Temp = 25
    }
};
```

Which would yield

```
{
  "LiftPositioner": {
    "LiftMax": 5,
    "LiftMin": 0
  },
  "Temperature": {
    "CH0_Temp": 25,
    "CH1_Temp": 25
  }
}
```